# Getting Jenkins to download PDF from a link and send it as an email attachment

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using SonarQube to analyse a project every time Jenkins finishes a build. I have a plugin for SonarQube called PDF plugin which generates a PDF report for the code analysis. I know that there is a commercial version of PDF Plugin which does allow PDF's to be attached and sent to recipients. However, I want to know if there is a way to export PDF's without the commercial version. Basically, the PDF will be generated and posted as a link on a website. I want Jenkins to download the PDF and then send it to a list of recipients.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.15 the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for Jenkins can attach files that match a pattern to mails. That should do it if you previously download the PDF to the workspace using e.g. `wget` or `curl` as part of a shell build step.

Comment: Thanks. That seems like a good solution. I will add a post-build step after Sonar that will retrieve the PDF.